# How I print nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, nested

```
score = {
    'Messi' : {
        'English': 40,
        'Spanish' :100,
        'Portuguese':60},
    'Ronaldo': {
        'English': 70,
        'Spanish' :50,
        'Portuguese':100}}
```

I want to print  the value of 'english' of 'Ronaldo'.

Answer (score 1):

You can print it in python 2 using:

```
print score['Ronaldo']['English']
```

And in python 3 using:

```
print (score['Ronaldo']['English'])
```

Comment: I think more people use Python 3 than Python 2.

Comment: There's people who still uses python 2. But I added both ways for people who uses python 3. Thanks for your comment @jar.